# Mockito using argument matchers for when call on method with variable number of arguments

Tags: java, mockito

I am attempting to use argument matchers inside a when call to a method that has a variable number of arguments (the `...` thing in Java) without success.  My code is below and I'll also list all of the lines I tried using to make this work.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class MethodTest {
    public String tripleDot(String... args) {
        String sum = "";
        for (String i : args) {
            sum += i;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            MethodTest mt = mock(MethodTest.class);
            when(mt.tripleDot((String[])anyObject())).thenReturn("Hello world!");
            System.out.println(mt.tripleDot(new String[]{"1","2"}));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass().toString() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

If print statement is:

```
System.out.println(mt.tripleDot(new String[]{"1"}));
```

or

```
System.out.println(mt.tripleDot("1"));
```

It will print "Hello world."

But if the print statement is:

```
System.out.println(mt.tripleDot(new String[]{"1","2"}));
```

or

```
System.out.println(mt.tripleDot("1","2"));
```

It will print "null".

I've also tried doing variations in the when call, such as `anyObject()` or `anyString()` but to no avail.  I'm not sure if Mockito can handle using argument matchers in regard to method calls that include a variable number of arguments.  Is it even possible?  If so, what should I be doing to make this work?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try the [`anyVararg()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.5/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#anyVararg()) matcher. This was introduced in 1.8.1.

Comment: I feel so embarrassed right now.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Andrew, Don't worry..it happens to us all. That's how we learn. :D

Comment: I needed a extra minute to find the correct syntax: `Matchers.<NeededType> anyVararg()`

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: seems is @Deprecated

Comment: `anyVararg()` is deprecated now. Use [`any()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.5/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any()) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Try `Mockito.anyVararg()`. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito.anyVararg()` is deprecated as of `2.1.0`. Preferable to use `ArgumentMatchers.any()` or `ArgumentMatchers.any(class)`.