# Mockito stub method that has many arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test, springmockito

I wanted to stub a method that has 6 arguments without having to write any() each time

So instead of

```
 when( service.method(any() , any() , any() , .. ).thenReturn( new  ArrayList<>() ) ;
```

is it possible to somehow write

```
 when( servicemethod( *anyNumberOfArgument()* )thenReturn( new ArrayList<>() ) ;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito using argument matchers for when call on method with variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214311/mockito-using-argument-matchers-for-when-call-on-method-with-variable-number-of)

Comment: @Matteo sounds to me like the method has a fixed number of arguments.

Comment: @slauth it has, but he doesn't seem to care (see the pseudo-code he proposed)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write a little helper method:

```java
private OngoingStubbing<List<String>> whenServiceMethodIsCalled() {
    return when(service.method(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any()));
}
```

And then use it from your test code:

```java
whenServiceMethodIsCalled().thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
```